# Is the set of sinusoidal functions with period $2\pi$ closed under addition?

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry

Let $w: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be an element of B iff there exist $A \in \mathbb{R}_{ \geq 0}$ and $\phi \in [0, 2\pi)$ such that $w(t) = A \sin(t+\phi)$. Is B a linear subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}}$ ? By a [theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_subspace#Definition_and_useful_characterization_of_subspace), B is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}}$ iff:

1. The zero function is in B ;
2. If $w_{1} (t)$ and $w_{2} (t)$ are elements of B, then $w_{1} (t) + w_{2} (t)$ is an element of B, too ;
3. If $w (t)$ is an element of B and $c(t)$ is a scalar function of $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}}$, then $(c \cdot w) (t) $ is an element of B as well.

I'd like to verify the second point. So I define $w_{1} (t) := A_{1} \sin (t + \phi_{1})$ and $w_{2} (t) := A_{2} \sin( t + \phi_{2})$ and see if we can find an $A_{3}$ and $\phi_{3}$ such that $w_{1} (t) + w_{2} (t) = A_{3} \sin (t + \phi_{3} ) \qquad (3)$.

We can rewrite the left side of $(3)$ by writing it as $$ A_{1} (\sin(t)\cos(\phi_{1} 
) + \cos(t)\sin(\phi_{1})) + A_{2} (\sin(t)\cos(\phi_{2}) + \cos(t)\sin(\phi_{2})) \quad .$$

Furthermore, we can rewrite the right side in a way that it is *almost* similar: (provided we set $A_{3} = A_{1} + A_{2}$)  $$ A_{1} (\sin(t)\cos(\phi_{3}) + \cos(t)\sin(\phi_{3})) + A_{2} (\sin(t)\cos(\phi_{3}) + \cos(t)\sin(\phi_{3})) \quad.  $$

However, I'm not sure I've shown closure under addition now. Because the way I did it, the two expressions are only equal when $\phi_{1} = \phi_{3}$ *and* $\phi_{2} = \phi_{3}$, so $\phi_{1} = \phi_{2}$. But I thought equality ought to be able to hold for arbitrarily chosen $\phi_{1}$ and $\phi_{2}$, so not necessarily when they're equal.

Have I shown additivity now? If not, can you help me to do it?

Comment: The easiest way to go about it is to observe that $A\sin(t+\phi)=\operatorname{Im}(ze^{it})$ where $z=Ae^{i\phi}$. So $A_1\sin(t+\phi_1)+A_2\sin(t+\phi_2)=A_3\sin(t+\phi_3)$ where $A_3$ and $\phi_3$ are the magnitude and phase of the complex number $z_3=z_1+z_2=A_1e^{i\phi_1}+A_2e^{i\phi_2}$. You can do it without complex numbers too, for example by reverse engineering the above steps, but it's a little more tedious.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not totally sure how to make your approach work. But you have, by expanding $A_1\sin(t+\phi_1)+A_2\sin(t+\phi_2)$,
\begin{align}
&A_1\cos(\phi_1)\sin(t)+A_1\sin(\phi_1)\cos(t)+A_2\cos(\phi_2)\sin(t)+A_2\sin(\phi_2)\cos(t)\\ \ \\
=&(A_1\cos(\phi_1)+A_2\cos(\phi_2))\,\sin(t)+(A_1\sin(\phi_1)+A_2\sin(\phi_2))\,\cos(t).
\end{align}
Now, to simplify notation, we need to show that $\alpha\,\sin t+\beta\cos t$ is of the form you want. The key observation is now that, for any $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb R$, we can always find $\phi$ with 
$$
\cos \phi=\frac\alpha{(|\alpha|^2+|\beta|^2)^{1/2}},\ \ \ \ 
\sin \phi=\frac\alpha{(|\alpha|^2+|\beta|^2)^{1/2}}.
$$
Then
\begin{align}
\alpha\sin t+\beta\cos t
&=(|\alpha|^2+|\beta|^2)^{1/2}\,(\cos\phi\,\sin t+\sin\phi\,\cos t)\\ \ \\
&=(|\alpha|^2+|\beta|^2)^{1/2}\,\sin(t+\phi).
\end{align}

---

Note that the same argument can be used to show that linear combinations of sines of any period are still multiples of $\sin(t+\phi)$.